# How to determine when ckeditor is done loading

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor

I need to determine when ckeditor is done loading so I can get correct dimensions of the containing div afterwards. Currently my call to do that occurs before ckeditor is done so the div is not it's final size.

I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322284/when-is-a-ckeditor-instance-well-and-truly-loaded) which seems to be asking the same thing but I don't have the context, i.e. I don't know how that person is invoking ckeditor. The accepted answer:

```
editor.on('contentDom', function(e) {
set_up_style_stuff();
});
```

does nothing, unsurprisingly. I don't know what 'editor' represents there.

I'm adding it this way:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.TextContent, new { @class = "ckeditor", @id = "text-content", @name = "cke1"})
```

and then I call:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('text-content');
```

What I really want is a callback from that statement that tells me when it's complete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach to `contentDom` event like this:

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('text-content').on('contentDom', function (e) {
            set_up_style_stuff();
        });
```

Comment: This actually seems to work, but rather inconsistently I'm afraid. :{

Comment: Can you try `instanceReady` event instead?

Comment: Thanks Mathew, but it wasn't this that wasn't working predictably. After this completes I was calling a function to position the element. In that function was a var windowheight=$(window).height() and var elementheight = $("#id").height(). This last one was causing my scrollbar to jump, invalidating 'windowheight'. Why? Not positive, but #id was display:hidden. I think .height() might have changed it's visibility to get it's height, causing it to take up space in the dom. 
Just conjecture. But I'm officially crazy now after a few hours of this.

Comment: Is it possible to recreate a minimal version in JsFiddle?

Comment: That would be pretty tough. But your answer was correct for what I asked. If need be I'll formulate another question for this issue.